# How to get result from Count Query that shows in Query Datasheet view?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to get the result of a Count query. I need to know if it's greater than 0.

My code:

```vb
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdg = db.QueryDefs("quyGpSumReportCount")
qdg.Sql = Replace(qdg.Sql, "plugtable", VigilTable)
qdg.Sql = Replace(qdg.Sql, "plugchurch", "'" & vChurch & "'")
Set rst = qdg.OpenRecordset("quyGpSumReportCount")
Debug.Print "Total = " & rst!Total
PartCnt = rst!Total
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
```

The query looks like this for the first church once the replacements have been made:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS Total
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t.fldUserID, v.[fldChurch/Parish] FROM tblSpring2022 _
AS t INNER JOIN tblVolunteers AS v ON t.[fldUserID] = v.[ID] WHERE _
 (v.[fldChurch/Parish] = '1548 Heights'))  AS [%$##@_Alias];
```

Since I don't change back to the query after running it, I can switch to the Datasheet view and see the results. In the Field Totals, there is one entry and it's value is 1.  (I've run it with a couple of different churches and get different but accurate values, including 0 for a few.)

Every attempt I've made to capture the value, using the name of the field, Total, or Fields(0) or rst.Fields(0) or anything else comes up Null.

So the query is running and returning the correct result but am unable to access that result from within VBA.

Comment: Where's the rest of the SQL - everything before FROM? The Debug.Print always returns Null?

Comment: Sorry, I left out the COUNT line:
```SELECT Count(*) AS Total
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t.fldUserID, v.[fldChurch/Parish] FROM plugtable AS t INNER JOIN tblVolunteers AS v ON t.[fldUserID] = v.[ID] WHERE (v.[fldChurch/Parish] = plugchurch))  AS [%$##@_Alias];``` Debug.Print doesn't return NULL, it just doesn't print anything to the immediate window.  Thanks.

Comment: Should edit your question, not just show in comment.

Comment: Why do you need to modify query object? What is the SQL of query object before modifying? Do you have a separate table for each church? Or a field for each church? In either case, not normalized structure. Strongly advise not to use punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Comment: You have `qdg.OpenRecordset`. That triggers runtime error for me and I don't see how you even get to the Debug line. This works `db.OpenRecordset`.

Comment: I need to modify the recordset because I use the same query for different tables.  The database is to keep track of our volunteers and their hours during different vigils.  I have one table called tblVolunteers that has all the personal information (name, phone, church, etc.) for each volunteer.  And another table for each of our vigils, Spring2021, Fall2021, Spring2022, etc.  Since those tables are all the same, when I need to run a query against any of them, I put in the name of the particular table in place of plugtable and, in this case, the the name of the church in place of plugchurch.

Comment: I used qdg.OpenRecordset because I'm already using qdf.openrecordset and I couldn't find any information that said I couldn't.  But I think you're right.  The code for this button begins with On Error Resume Next and I forgot that was there, which is why I didn't get an error until I commented that out.  Leaving me with a question, can I reuse qdf while a qdf query is still open?  (The church I'm looking for with this query is the next on a list from a previous query for all churches.)  I really don't understand how some of this works, to be honest.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, IMO, should not be a table for each vigil - one table with a field to identify the period. Instead of modifying query object, just apply filter to form or report or recordset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I didn't solve this, you guys did; but it is solved.

For reasons that entirely escape me, qdg.OpenRecordset and qdf.OpenRecordset both resulted in a Data Conversion Error.  But db.OpenRecordset, suggested above, works perfectly.  Not only does it run but the result of the query finds its way both into a MsgBox and into the textbox on the form, making it possible for me to use it.

If I could upvote comments I would; the solution is, after all, there.

Thanks to all!

Comment: Mark your answer as accepted. You can flag comments as useful.

Comment: Database opens recordset, query does not open recordset.

Comment: Review the doc for [QueryDef.OpenRecordset method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydef-openrecordset-method-dao) and then try with just `Set rst = qdg.OpenRecordset` (without trying to supply the query's name as the method's *Type* parameter).